# Java android capture photo with custom resolution

Tags: java, android

I want to do this : I choose a resolution next I set the closest resolution and take a photo , but I don't know how I get a list of resolution and set a resolution.
I take a photo just like this :

```
  private void clickpic() {
        // Check Camera
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // Open default camera
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            // start the image capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), R.string.no_camera, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not grant you control over the resolution. The closest thing that it does is let you choose between a full-size image (provided if you supply `EXTRA_OUTPUT`) or a thumbnail (provided if you do not supply `EXTRA_OUTPUT`).

Comment: So I can't do it what I want ?

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka: Not with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. You are welcome to use the camera APIs directly, though this is very complicated.

Comment: Could you give me some examples , I can't find

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka: About 1% of the code that you need can be found [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html). As I wrote, working with the camera APIs is very complicated.